# How to ignore .local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ when importing a module to python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, amazon-ec2

I have tried importing pandas from local pkg , which has 1.1.12 version ,

But I have another path where it has lower version 1.0.1 ,

When i `import pandas` in python script , as a default it is picking up 1.1.12 version which i do't want to happen. I have tried removing that path from `sys.remove.path('.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')` as first line in my code , still it is picking the same one than 1.0.1 ?

any suggesting to only import modules/pkgs other than .local ones ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this why not try to do this in a virtual enviorment? as it will be forced to take your specific file only

Hope it helped! :D